# the fundamental group acts on half upper plan

Tags: surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $S$ be a compact oriental surface without boundary of genus $g\ge 2$, then its universal covering is $\mathbb{H}^2$, I am confused with 2 facts following:

(1) $\rho:\pi_1(S)\hookrightarrow Isom^+(\mathbb{H}^2)$,

(2) $\forall \gamma\in \pi_1(S)$, $\gamma\ne Id$, then $\rho(\gamma)$ is hyperbolique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you state an explicit question regarding your confusion. Otherwise, it is difficult to know quite what kind of help you need to allay your confusion.